# Type cast error with postgresql using python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
import psycopg2

conn=None
try:
 conn=psycopg2.connect(database="LIS", user="postgres",password="postgres",host="localhost",port=5432)
except:
    print("Unable to connect")

if conn:
    id="FCS01"
    cur=conn.cursor()
    query="""
    SELECT faculty_fname FROM faculty where id=?
    """
    cur.execute(query,(id,))
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    print(rows[0][0])
```

It gives an error
*No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast.*
however it work when we directly write value of id like-

```
SELECT faculty_fname FROM faculty where id="FCS01"
```

Comment: What is the column type for `faculty_fname.id`, integer, text, character varying?

Comment: Isn't the syntax ```where id=%s```, per https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries? Looks fine otherwise